# Best layout configurations for multiple screen support

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I spent the last week creating all these darn layouts for my app update and I still get complaints about the layouts on my app reviews! I am a newby for Android and not quite sure what the best route to go for multiple screen support!

[image: My Android Layouts]

Here's what I have so far! I feel like a big idiot and that I wasted a lot of time doing everything the wrong way.  Would love some advice on how I could create the best configurations to fit all screens besides wearables,

Benjamin

Heres another picture that might help my case

[image: the whole view]

Comment: I’m trying to have my android app support multiple layouts and I created various layouts to hopefully cover everything. But the pixel density is where I still have issues with I’m assuming. All in all I’m looking for the best way to achieve a more responsive UI through the layouts.

Comment: What does your screen look like? A fitness app? A shopping list? A note taking app? A map with restaurants? If you get a little bit more specific then we will be better able to help you. My advice so far: you can provide different resources depending on screen size and density. This means *resources* not just layout files. Sometimes one layout will do the job if you provide more than one version of a dimen value.

Comment: I've add another picture if it helps my case!

Comment: Useful links for getting started: [https://material.io/](https://material.io/) for what you should try to achieve, [http://www.androiddocs.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html](http://www.androiddocs.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [http://www.androiddocs.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html](http://www.androiddocs.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for technical aspects of supporting multiple screen types. Maybe reading this will lead to more specific questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a LinearLayout and setting a layout weight on child views of the LinearLayout can be a good way of applying flexible design. Obviously in cases where it's appropriate to use a LinearLayout.

For example you might have a LinearLayout with two LinearLayout child views. One view you'd like to take up a third of the display, and the other view two thirds. This could be fiddly to set for multiple different displays as on a smaller device it might be 300dp and 600dp but on a larger device it will likely be something very different. However, by using layout weight the proportions will automatically be calculated. Eg:

```
<LinearLayout
  android: orientation="vertical"
  android: layout_width="match_parent"
  android: layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
  android: orientation="vertical"
  android: layout_width="match_parent"
  android: layout_height="0dp"
  android: layout_weight="1">

    ...

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
  android: orientation="horizontal"
  android: layout_width="match_parent"
  android: layout_height="0dp"
  android: layout_weight="2">

    ...

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is general because the question is not specific:

Supporting multiple screens sizes is tricky. You need to think more towards Wrap Content and Match Parent than towards actual dp widths and heights. dp will give you the same length on all screens, and most of the times, this is not what you want. Make use of RelativeLayout to set the position of layouts relative to others, or LinearLayout to align layouts and views.
The most important thing is to avoid setting a fixed width and height except if that is what you need (for example, you might want to have a fixed height for a button on all screen sizes).

Comment: Everything from the UIImageViews, Webviews, Buttons and more are using match_parent with constraints depending on the the device, I set each constraint to the proper one depending on the screen size, but its mainly the density pixels that are changing the size of the buttons. I read somewhere that sw320dp and sw720dp etc. would be the best way to go but I'd hate to redo more layouts and still get the same results :(